# How to override stream closing when returning stream C#

Tags: c#, .net, stream, return, memorystream

I would like to be able to return `MemoryStream` from my function but I think that when returning the `stream` its also *automatically closed*.

```
using (var httpStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(link)) 
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        await httpStream.CopyToAsync(stream); 
        return stream;    
    }
}
```

Is there any way to maybe `override` this so I can return `stream` so I can use it elsewhere.

Here's how I'm trying to use it in *another method*:

```
using (var fielStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    Stream stream = await GetStreamAsync(videoid, type, quality);

    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);  
}
```

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO Tour section as it shows how SO works. The How do I ask a good question? may help. In addition, you may find the SO Asking section useful. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Remove `using`: it is the caller who should `Dispose` the stream

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Answer (score 0):

Drop inner `using`: it is the caller (who calls for creation) should `Dispose` the stream:

```
using (var httpStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(link)) {
  var stream = new MemoryStream();

  try {
    await httpStream.CopyToAsync(stream); 

    return stream;    
  }
  catch {
    stream.Dispose();

    throw;
  } 
}
```

It is the *caller* who should put `using`, like this:

```
// We create MemoryStream with the code above (GetStreamAsync) 
/ and then Dispose the stream 
using (var stream = await GetStreamAsync(...)) {
  ...
}
```